# How do I send objects that will contain different type of data including some ArrayList in Firebase with Android?

Tags: android, object, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I know  how to write data in Firebase from Android. But I can only write single type of data. Like this:

```
databaseRef.child("Players").child("time").setValue("It is time");
```

This will write "It is time" value inside these two child nodes in Firebase. I know it is easy to do this from Firebase adding nodes and adding data.

I want to do it programatically in Android. For example under "time" child, I want to have an object like this:

```
time

    |
        0
         key value
         key value
```

As you can see under object with index `0`, I have an array of keys values. So how can I send an object with java in Firebase with different type of data?

EDIT

As you need more information about what i need this is a class i made it.

Time.class

```
public class Time {

String start;
String finish;
String breaktime;

public Time(String breaktime, String finish, String start) {
    this.breaktime = breaktime;
    this.finish = finish;
    this.start = start;
}

public String getBreaktime() {
    return breaktime;
}

public void setBreaktime(String breaktime) {
    this.breaktime = breaktime;
}

public String getFinish() {
    return finish;
}

public void setFinish(String finish) {
    this.finish = finish;
}

public String getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(String start) {
    this.start = start;
}
```

}

Directions.class

```
public class Directions {

String from;
String bd;
String basement;
String cave;
String cityHall;


public Directions(String basement, String bd, String cave, String cityHall, String from) {
    this.basement = basement;
    this.bd = bd;
    this.cave = cave;
    this.cityHall = cityHall;
    this.from = from;
}

public String getBasement() {
    return basement;
}

public void setBasement(String basement) {
    this.basement = basement;
}

public String getBd() {
    return bd;
}

public void setBd(String bd) {
    this.bd = bd;
}

public String getCave() {
    return cave;
}

public void setCave(String cave) {
    this.cave = cave;
}

public String getCityHall() {
    return cityHall;
}

public void setCityHall(String cityHall) {
    this.cityHall = cityHall;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}
```

}

MainActivity.class

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Time time = new Time("10min","34min 3sec","48min");
    Game nName = new Game("Shit Happens");

    myRef.child("Golie").child("Br").setValue(time,nName);



}
```

This gives me error

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class game.com.game.Game

Comment: Try to give us a little more code so we know what you are trying to do - an example if the sort of object you want to save in firebase.

Comment: Is it good now? I edited my question with more info

Comment: @Doodle Yep - much better- has the answer below solved your problem? If so you must accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firebase** allow You to add an object of nested classes very efficient
i will explain a small example of how to save an object of `MyModel` calss into **firebase**

save your data you want to save into **Firebase** in a separate  class like this one:

```
public class MyModel{
    public String name;
    public String collegeId;
    public String faculty;
    public String specialization;
    public String year;
    public String mobileNumber;
    public String emailAddress;
    public String projectName;
    public String projectDescription;
    public String projectOfferedSolution;
    public String projectAddress;
    private String projectPhases;
}
```

then get a reference to you child

```
 mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mProjectsDatabaseReference = 
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Projects");
```

Make an instance of MyModel class and set your value inside it

```
MyModel model=new MyModel();

      model.Address(mProjectAddress.getText().toString());
                model.Name(mProjectName.getText().toString());
                model.Description(mProjectDescription.getText().toString());
                model.OfferedSolution(mProjectSolution.getText().toString());
                model.Phases(mProjecPhases.getText().toString());
```

**then**
add send your data object to firebase

```
mProjectsDatabaseReference.push().setValue(model);
```

See the result in this image from Firebase console app

[image: Firebase result image :]